# Windows 10's 3-finger emulation of middle button: Click, hold, drag, release?

Tags: x11, laptop, touchpad

I asked X-windows users how they obtain full [3-button functionality](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552605/x-window-requirement-for-3-mouse-buttons-on-a-modern-windows-laptop) on Windows 10 laptops, which generally lack a middle button.  I *assumed* that Windows 10's multi-finger tap emulation of different mouse buttons does not allow for click, hold, drag, and release.  I found confirmation of this in a post of the [exact same problem](http://superuser.com/questions/1267316/alternative-to-autohotkey-to-middle-click-and-drag-on-a-trackpad-with-windows-10) 2 years ago, but I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment and ask what the eventual solution was.

I'm worried that by moving to Windows 10, I'll be at the mercy of having to haul around a mouse wherever I might go, and being handcuffed on frequent occassions in which I don't have it.

**Examples of middle mouse dragging functions in a mixed Unix/Windows environment**

- `xterm`: Pulls up various context menus
- `xpdf`: Panning (`xpdf` works well with `LaTeX` because the PDF file can be updated without closing the viewer)
- `Inkscape`: Middle mouse drag is used for panning, among other things
- `Word`: Panning
- `Excel`: Panning

**Possible solution, requiring confirmation:**  I found [suggested registry edits](http://nikles.it/2017/uncategorized/touchpad-three-fingers-tap-as-middle-click-and-drag-and-drop-on-finger-lift-no-delay-on-windows-10-after-creators-update) online (captured below).  ***If a kind soul with Windows 10 can confirm that it works,*** I would be eternally grateful (for the next 10 years). It would remove a fundamental road block to my abandoning the sinking Windows 7 for the safety of Windows 10.

I'll probably still try to find a touchpad with real buttons, though unsuccessfully.  The single piece touch pad with clickable corners works poorly for me.  When I reach down to click the lower right corner to emulate a right button click, I unintentionally move the pointer.

*Three Fingers Tap as Middle Click*

Let’s fix the Three Fingers Tap behavior. I want to disable `Cortana` and enable the middle click button.

- Open the Start menu and type `regedit`. Open it (and give it all the authorizations it needs to make changes to your computer).
- On the left panel navigate to this location
- `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`
- In the right panel search for `Tap_Three_Finger` and double click it. Set its value to `2`
- Eventually check that the `Tap_Three_Finger_Enable` is set to `1`.

*No Delay for Drop when Dragging (drop on finger lift)*

- Again in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`
- Search for the `Drag_Radio` key.
- Set its value to `2` to immediately drop on finger lift.

Done. Now the three finger tap will be a middle click and the drag and drop will be instantaneous.

**Afternote:** The big uncertainty that I noticed above is that it refers to ElanTech software.  It might not be native to Windows 10.

Comment: The real "fringe" is using the built-in trackpad for anything other than emergency. *Of course* everybody who is using a laptop for real work is carrying around a mouse. (And very few applications have a useful use for middle click-drag-release.)

Comment: You are looking at the subset of people that use Hardware: trackpad, OS: Windows 10: Windowing system: X11.

Comment: Is this a Unix question?

Comment: I'd say that the question is more aligned with the Unix stack exchange than the Superuser stack exchange.  There are more Windows machines than Unix machines, so I suspect that it's more likely for a unix user to rely on a Windows machine than the reverse.  In other words, I expect the question to be of relevance to a greater portion of the unix crowd than the Superuser crowd.  But in terms of hard numbers, I don't know what portion of Unix users rely on machines designed with Windows in mind.